# Как изменить возвращаемый из `outputtypehandler` тип данных datetime на строку?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Возможно ли изменить тип данных `datetime`, возвращаемых из `outputtypehandler` на строку формата `yyyymmdd`?

```
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType in (cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_DATE):
        return cursor.var(datetime.date,cursor.arraysize)
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Change datetime.date type in outputtypehandler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65376907) от участника [@Babar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12802756/babar)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65376907

Answer (score 2):

Следующий код:

```
import cx_Oracle 

connection = cx_Oracle.connect ('connection_string')

def OutputTypeHandler (cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType in (cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP_TZ, cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_DATE):
        return cursor.var (cx_Oracle.STRING, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

connection.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler 

with connection.cursor () as cursor:
    sql = """
        alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYYMMDD' nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYYMMDD'
    """
    cursor.execute (sql)

    sql = """select systimestamp, sysdate from dual"""
    for r in cursor.execute(sql):
        print(r)
```

Выведет:

```
('20201223', '20201223')
```

Если пользоваться NLS настройками формата даты на стороне клиента, как показано выше, не стоит забывать использовать [session callback](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#session-callbacks-for-setting-pooled-connection-state) для выполнения `ALTER` с пулом сессий. Но возможно, было бы лучше явное преобраование с маской формата `YYYYMMDD` в самом SQL запросе.

Если интересуют другие типы дат с часовыми поясами, то нужно добавить их в условие `if defaultType` и  `ALTER`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65387573) от участника [@Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones)</sub>